# Fix application session timeout that is logged in as SSO in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

We have an application running in `tomcat` server The application session timeout is set as 3 hours. This application is an `ServiceProvider` configured as a `SingleSignOn` in Microsoft Azure.

Without `SSO` configuration the application session expires after 3 hours, with `SSO` the application session expires in 20 minutes.

How to extend the session expiration to 3 hours with the `SSO`? the `SSO` is done through Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Have you checked the tokenlifetime policy?

Comment: Any idea on which attribute in SAML response has this token lifetime? or should i check in the configuration of Microsoft Azure?

Comment: For the token lifetime policy, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#cmdlet-reference).

Comment: Thanks SunnySun this was helpful